# Jenkins apply button pops up blank error page

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline

I was using Jenkins for a while and everything was working perfectly fine. But two or three days back i need to change some configuration for one of my project and when i hit apply button after performing those change. This error screen appears. Even i don't change anything and click apply button same error screen pops up.
[image: Jenkins_error]

I am currently using Jenkins version 2.265
this error occur when i hit this button
[image: Jenkins_apply_button]

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, it was because of "dark mode extension" on google chrome. It was ok on firefox, but chrome not. I suggest to disable dark mode extension on chrome when using jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I downgrade jenkins to version 2.263 and everything starts working fine. So i think this issue is specific to Jenkins version 2.265

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was caused by the now deprecated Coverity plugin. I would suggest you to check your deprecated plugins that add a section/options in the configuration and remove them.

Comment: I had a lot of deprecated plugins. After I updated and restarted Jenkins, the issue is gone.